# Giving table child rows data from the parent row

Tags: javascript, vue.js, html-table, datatable, element-ui

I'm needing to know what the parent row ID is when a child row is clicked so my thought is to give each child row the ID of the parent so we can get the data that way. Currently trying to find a way to do that within the code that loops through the backend data and formats each row for the table.

[image]

```
tableContent() {
      if (this.$store.state.models.models) {
        // store the function
        const mapper = (model) => ({
          name: model.children ? (
            <span class='model'>
              {model.year} {model.name} <span class='hide'>{model.id}</span>
              <button class='add-trim' onClick={this.addTrimDrawer}>
                <PlusIcon class='plus-icon' /> add trim
              </button>
            </span>
          ) : (
            <span class='edit-trim' onClick={this.editTrimDrawer}>
              {model.name} <span>{model.trim_id}</span>
              <EditIcon class='edit-icon' />
            </span>
          ),
          id: model.trim_id ? `trim-${model.trim_id}` : `model-${model.id}`,
          technical: model.children ? null : <ChecklistIcon class='tech checklist-icon' />,
          customer_delivery: model.children ? null : <ChecklistIcon class='cd checklist-icon' />,
          customer_acceptance: model.children ? null : <ChecklistIcon class='ca checklist-icon' />,
          off_the_truck: model.children ? null : <ChecklistIcon class='oft checklist-icon' />,
          vim: model.children ? null : <ChecklistIcon class='vim checklist-icon' />,
          // use it for children, if there are any
          children: model.children?.map(mapper),
        });

        // use it for the models
        this.tableData = this.$store.state.models.models.map(mapper);
      }
    },
```

Comment: It looks like you are storing HTML in state. Shouldn't you be using a template instead? Also please try to make a [mcve]

Comment: This is using element UI so it has to be in state